# android emulator not creating

Tags: android, android-emulator

I tried creating an an AVD in eclipse but even after filling up all the fields the OK button does not get activated . the fields I fill up are

1)AVD name
2)Device
3) SD card

the rest are prepopulated

edit: a SC of my emulator

http://imgur.com/atlw26g

Comment: Add screenshot of your AVD manager showing how you try to define your device so we can see what you left out.

Comment: @MarsAtomic added screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you did not install the "System Image" for that API. That's why it can't find any CPU/ABI options.

Open SDK Manager and search for System Image under for example Android 4.2.2 (API 17).

You should find something like 'ARM EABI v7a System Image', 'Intel x86 Atom System Image'.
Install those and you should be able create AVD after that.

Comment: Eclipse > Window Menu > Android SDK Manager menu item.  Then look through and find the images that you need and download them.  After that, things should work fine.